# optimal negative space between rectangles algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, geometry

Given rectangles r[ ] inside of larger rectangle R, is there an optimal speedy algorithm for determining the minimum number of rectangles that fill in the "[negative space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnboe.png)" between r[ ]?

For example, given these three blue rectangles inside of the purple rectangle:

[image: three blue rectangles inside of a purple rectangle]

How could I quickly determine a list of rectangles like these in green below (which may not be the optimal configuration, hence my post):

[image: green rectangles in between the blue rectangles]

Comment: it looks like the algorithm in your example scans from top to bottom looking for obstructions.  When it finds one, it completes the current fill-rectangle and starts two new ones.  When it finds an end to an obstruction it completes the current adjacent fill-rectangle(s) and starts a new one of a larger size.

Comment: This might be related to the more general question of, given a collection of rectangles, finding the smallest number of rectangles that precisely cover those rectangles.  I'm not sure what algorithms exist for that problem, but if there's an efficient way of solving that problem it should give you an efficient solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What oosterwal describes is a special case of trapezoidal decomposition, a well-understood primitive in computational geometry typically used for point location in a planar subdivision. It can be implemented in time O(n log n) with a reasonable constant.

When the rectangles are in general position, it will return a "rectangulation" with # green rectangles = 3 * # blue rectangles + 1, and this is optimal. The L-shaped neighborhood of each blue corner *must* be cut in one direction or the other by a green segment (general position: we can't use the same segment for two blue rectangles), so for each blue rectangle, we add <strike>4 green edges</strike> 8 green edges and 4 vertices (4 new edges plus 4 subdivided), decreasing the number of connected components by 1 in the process. The result by the polyhedral formula is 3 more faces (rectangles):

V - E + F = 1 + # connected components.

---

Example:

```
 0123456789abc
0+-----------+
1|           |
2|  +--+     |
3|  |R | +-+ |
4|  +--+ |S| |
5|       | | |
6| +--+  | | |
7| |T |  +-+ |
8| +--+      |
9+-----------+
```

We're running a sweep line from top to bottom. The events are

```
# (y, whichside, xmin, xmax)
(2, top, 3, 6)  # R
(3, top, 8, a)  # S
(4, bot, 3, 6)  # R
(6, top, 2, 5)  # T
(7, bot, 8, a)  # S
(8, bot, 2, 5)  # T
```

We set up a binary search tree ordered by x that holds the partially constructed green rectangles. I'll write it as a list.

```
# (xmin, xmax, ymin)
(0, c, 0)
```

Now we start processing events. First is (2, top, 3, 6). We find that it's nested inside the only green rectangle so far, (xmin=0, xmax=c, ymin=0, ymax=2). (The blue interval always nests as long as the blue rectangles don't intersect.) We start two new green rectangles, one on each side of the blue rectangle, and the search tree contains

```
(0, 3, 2) (6, c, 2)
```

Now we process (3, top, 8, a). The interval (8, a) nests inside (6, c), so we finish another rectangle (xmin=6, xmax=c, ymin=2, ymax=3) and start two more:

```
(0, 3, 2) (6, 8, 3) (a, c, 3)
```

Now we process (4, bot, 3, 6). This ends the green rectangles to its left and right, (xmin=0, xmax=3, ymin=2, ymax=4) and (xmin=6, xmax=8, ymin=3, ymax=4). The search tree is

```
(0, 8, 4) (a, c, 3)
```

I think things should be clear by this point. Here is the finished rectangulation:

```
 0123456789abc
0+-----------+
1|           |
2+--+--+-----|
3|  |R |-+-+-|
4+--+--+-|S| |
5|       | | |
6+-+--+--+ | |
7| |T +--+-+-+
8+-+--+------+
9+-----------+
```

A note on handling degeneracies: put bottom events before top events with the same y-coordinate, and suppress rectangles with zero area. There will still be "unnecessary" rectangles in general, which a more sophisticated event processor could avoid (by handling all events at a given y-coordinate at once).

Comment: Can you give a bit more elaboration on this?  This looks really cool and I've love to see some more detail about it.

Comment: As oosterwal said, you can perform a plane sweep by sorting and processing the blue horizontal segments from top to bottom. When you encounter a blue top, terminate the green rectangle above it and begin two more. When you encounter a blue bottom, terminate the green rectangles to the left and right and begin a new one. Each of these operations is O(log n) with a binary tree storing the active green rectangles in order of x coordinate. Handling the degenerate cases is sort of a pain though...

Comment: OK, it's a bit sloppy to say that # connected components always decreases by 1. However, it does always go from # blue rectangles + 1 in the beginning to 1 at the end, so the math still works; we just have to amortize.

Comment: I would benefit from some high level pseudo-code...  having a tough time parsing this answer.