# An algorithm to group cells into rectangles

Tags: c, algorithm, multidimensional-array

[image: example diagram]

Imagine the picture above represents a 6*6 array of ints where 0 is black.
Is there a quick algorithm to split the non 0 cells into rectangles?
Ideally the check would be contained within a for loop, **without creating any other arrays**.

```
for(x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    for(y = 0; y < 6; y++)
        if(cellIsBottomRightOfRect(x,y)) {
            left = getLeft(x,y);
            top = getTop(x,y);
            printf("Rect: %d,%d %d,%d \n", left, top, x, y);
        }
```

Comment: Are there costs associated with moving an array element?

Comment: Do the cells in your rectangles have to be all the same color? Or just any non-zero color?  That is, can you have red and yellow cells in the same rectangle?  This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988271/optimal-negative-space-between-rectangles-algorithm might give you some insights.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: I believe the colors are meant to represent the output

Comment: what's your "fitness function" to determine a good rectangle decomposition from a bad one? minimum number of rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a recursive method which calls itself everytime it encounters a color different than the one it is trying to group at the moment?

Comment: I think this will be required but I can't work out the algorithm myself

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using a [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach?

Also, I think that a search algorithm (like A*) would work well here (even though it is has exponential time complexity).